# find records longer/shorter than a particular col

Tags: linux, shell, unix, awk, sed

this is my file: FILEABC.txt

```
Name|address|age|country
john|london|12|UK
adam|newyork|39|US|X12|123
jake|madrid|45|ESP
ram|delhi
joh|cal|34|US|788
```

I wanted to find the the header count in the file. so  i've this command

cat FILEABC.txt | awk --field-separator='|' '{print NF}' | sort -n |uniq -c

the result i get for this cmd is

cat FILEABC.txt | awk --field-separator='|' '{print NF}' | sort -n |uniq -c

```
  1 2
  3 4
  1 5
  1 6
```

My requirement is that, how do i find those records that have only 2 fields, 4 fields and so on from my file.
for ex,

if want to see the records having only 2 col:

```
 ram|delhi
```

if want to see rec's having more than 4 col:

```
adam|newyork|39|US|X12|123
```

Comment: simple `NF==2` and `NF>4` and so on?

Comment: what if i want to find those records having more than 4 fields

Comment: can you show me how to put it in awk . i'm new to this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to only print the records which have 2 fields then following may help you in same.

```
awk -F"|" 'NF==2'   Input_file
```

For any kind of records if you need a line which has more than 4 fields then change above condition to `NF>4` or you need line which have more than 5 fields eg--> `NF>5`

***Explanation:*** BY doing `-F"|"` I am making sure field separator is pipe here, then `NF` is an `awk` out of the box variable which defines the TOTAL number of fields in a line, so as per your request checking if number of fields are more than 2 here, if this condition is TRUE then print the current line(where I have NOT written print because `awk` works on method of condition and action, so if condition is TRUE here I am not mentioning any action and by default action print will happen for that line).

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk`, variable `NF` gives total number of fields in record/row, by default `awk` use single space as field separator, if you alter `FS`, it will calculate `NF` based on field separator mentioned, so what you can do is

```
awk -v FS='|' 'NF==2' infile
```

Which is same as

```
# Usual Syntax : awk 'condition { action }' infile

awk -v FS='|' 'NF==2{ print }' infile
```

For more than 4 fields,

```
awk -v FS='|' 'NF > 4' infile
```

Answer (score 1):

you can also use *grep* to filter 2-columed records:

```
grep '^[^|]*|[^|]*$' FILEABC.txt
```

It will output:

```
ram|delhi
```